# Cannot seed data in production using heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I had posted this question before but I haven't got any answers that solved my problem. Therefore, I am reposting this question.

I am using heroku to deploy my rails app. I am trying to seed some data in the production by running the command `heroku run rake db:seed.` However, the command is not working. I am not able to seed files in production. The `seeds.rb` file is given below.

```
#This file should contain all the record creation needed to seed the database with its default values.
#The data can then be loaded with the rake db:seed (or created alongside the db with db:setup).

#Examples:

  #cities = City.create([{ name: 'Chicago' }, { name: 'Copenhagen' }])
  #Mayor.create(name: 'Emanuel', city: cities.first)

#end


    5.times do              
    Scoreboard.create!(name_of_scoreboard: "scoreboard_abc",
                      name_of_organization: "abcdef",
                      name_of_activity: "ghijklmn",
                      user_id: 1,
                      states: "state",
                      country: "state",
                      cities: "state")
    end
```

$ heroku run rake db:seed
    Running rake db:seed on ⬢ app... up, run.4751
      ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"

I run `heroku restart` but the objects aren't seeded in the production database. I have tried seeding this file in development and it works perfectly. I am not sure what's wrong.

The heroku logs -t file is given below.

```
2016-06-22T00:50:58.882699+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:seed` by *******@gmail.com
2016-06-22T00:51:07.986301+00:00 heroku[run.1041]: Awaiting client
2016-06-22T00:51:08.026539+00:00 heroku[run.1041]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:seed`
2016-06-22T00:51:08.157630+00:00 heroku[run.1041]: State changed from starting to up
2016-06-22T00:51:12.891248+00:00 heroku[run.1041]: State changed from up to complete
2016-06-22T00:51:12.881329+00:00 heroku[run.1041]: Process exited with status 0
```

I have the database.yml file and seeds.rb files as part of gitignore. I am not sure if that might be the cause of the problem. I am pretty sure its not.

Comment: have you looked at `heroku logs --tail` to find the errors for your seed?

Comment: @maxpleaner, I haven't but I'll look at it now and post the log file as well.

Comment: @maxpleaner, I have posted the live log file from heroku. Not sure what is happening but the post request isn't going through

Comment: So the logs show no error. How sure are you that the seeds command is "not working"? Have you checked the console to see if any records are there?

Comment: @maxpleaner, the command works in development. I have tried that. I have ran the exact same command in production before and it has worked

Comment: @maxpleaner, I feel like heroku isn't even making the connection.

Comment: are you sure you pushed the latest version to heroku? By the way, looks like some lines in your seeds.rb file should be commented out. Everything before the `5.times do` block.

Comment: @maxpleaner, I have those commented out, only the 5.times block is running. The version of heroku is   heroku-cli/5.2.21-1a1f0bc (linux-amd64) go1.6.2

Comment: @kpaul have you run your migrations in production?

Comment: what i mean by "pushed the latest version to heroku" is doing a `git push heroku master`

Comment: @maxpleaner, yes I pushed latest changes to heroku. I ran heroku run rake db:migrate, migrations are good to go in production. I am able to sign up users in production just fine.

Comment: @kpaul so did you fix it ?

Comment: @Rico nope the problem still exists

Comment: `seeds.rb` should be in the repository in order for `rails` to seed it. If there is no `seeds.rb`, `rails` doesn't complain that the file is missing, instead it completes the `rake db:seed` task with out any error. So make sure you remove the `seeds.rb` from the `.gitignore` and push it to the repository.

Comment: @Dharam, I have taken the file out of gitignore, however, any changes I make to the seeds file are still not tracked. Is there an extra step I have to do.

Comment: Try `git add --force db/seeds.rb`

Comment: @Dharam, Thanks man. It worked. You can put your comment in an answer and i'll accept it as soon it allows me to do it. I can't believe such a small thing caused such as big confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`seeds.rb` should be in the repository in order for `rails` to seed it. If there is no `seeds.rb`, `rails` doesn't complain that the file is missing, instead it just completes the `rake db:seed` task with out any error.

So make sure you remove the `seeds.rb` from the `.gitignore`, add it to the `git` with `git add --force db/seeds.rb` and `git push` it to the repository.