# Installing bundler gives me "you don't have write permissions" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I had used ruby version manager (`rvm`) to install a new version of ruby. Running the command `rvm rubies`shows all the version of rubies that are installed. The list is given below.

```
rvm rubies

   ruby-1.9.3-p551 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.1.5 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.2.4 [ x86_64 ]
 * ruby-2.3.0 [ x86_64 ]
   ruby-2.3.1 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

I tried to run the command `bundle exec rake rb:mgirate` and I get the following error.

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:319:in `to_specs': Could not find 'bundler' (>= 0.a) among 5 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
Checked in 'GEM_PATH=:/nix/.nix-profile/lib/ruby/gems', execute `gem env` for more information
```

The error states that bundler isn't installed. I ran the command `gem install bundle` and I get the following error.

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /nix/.nix-profile/lib/ruby/gems directory.
```

It says that I don't have write permissions. I googled the error and it has something to do with updating ruby and ruby version. The reason why I updated to a new ruby version was because `heroku run rake db:seed` wasn't seeding data in production. I though it might be due to compatibility issues. Therefore, I decided to update to the new version of ruby. The servers, postgresql and everything else works fine. I can't run bundle because I can't install the gem. Any hep would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try to run `sudo chown -R \`whoami\` /nix/.nix-profile/lib/ruby/gems`

Comment: @mudasobwa, I was able to fix it. I had to specify which version to user. I simply ran rvm use 2.3.0 and it was both the current and the default version. It fixed the problem

Comment: @mudasobwa, I tried to open rails db and I got this error. Could not find 'railties' (>= 0.a) among 5 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError). I think the problem might still exist.

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` there?

Comment: @mudasobwa, No I didn't. I switched to a different ruby version therefore my gem dependencies also get switched. Once i restarted my workspace, it fixed everything.

Comment: @mudasobwa, The seed in production doesn't work but I have been dealing with that problem for like a week. No idea why

Comment: Please add a new question for your seeds not working, include what happens when you run it, the contents of your _seed.rb_, etc. This question has been answered already, if you found out a solution you should post it and select it as such.

Comment: @Leito, I have asked that question before on stack. The link is given below for the question. (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956727/cannot-seed-data-in-production-using-heroku).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was fixed by switching to the ruby version 2.3.0 by running the command rvm user 2.3.0. Once that is done you should restart the workspace. The reason for the error was the fact that when you switch ruby version it also changes gem files. Therefore, it wasn't able to recognize the gems.

Comment: Just wanted to note down that I think this is still relevant. I was getting the same write error with version 2.4.2. I uninstalled that and installed 2.3.3. I was able to install all of my gems after that. This is my first time working with Ruby and need to see if the rest of the environment works as it should.

Answer (score -2):

hey just add "**sudo**" at the beginning of your command. It will definitely work, because as the error says you don't have write permission. And if you will check the permission of that directory than you will find that only owner has write permission and as sudo takes us to the owner mode from user mode. Hence you will not get this error again. Please let me know if it doesn't works.

Comment: This actually is the solution - you just need to know the user password. Thanks Saurav.